# How to find column-wise NA's count without using group_by in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

How to get similar results using **dplyr** that we can get using `sapply` as following:

```
sapply(mtcars, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))

## mpg  cyl disp   hp drat   wt qsec   vs   am gear carb 
##    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0`

sapply(mtcars, function(x) sum(x))
##     mpg     cyl     disp       hp    drat       wt     qsec       vs       am     gear 
## 642.900 198.000 7383.100 4694.000 115.090  102.952  571.160   14.000   13.000  118.000 
##    carb 
##  90.000
```

Comment: `mtcars %>% summarise_all(funs(sum(is.na(.))))` and the second one is. `mtcars %>% summarise_all(sum)`

Comment: Beat me by 30 seconds